# how to make a counter add 1 only when the user inputs the keyowrd

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Do you want to add 1? if yes type in '0.01' ");
```

the problem with this is that it runs only once. I tried to add it inside a while loop (while(i > 100)) but it simply printed till 100 wihtout asking the user again

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;
        double yes = 0.01;

        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.println("Do you want to add 1? if yes type in '0.01' ");

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double add = keyboardInput.nextDouble();

        if (yes == add) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("i now is: " + i);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://nopaste.xyz/?26a11373ea47be51#lYvp5VBW2R9LRa+gDA9pe5z8rGvHi73SwQgfK4tyAYg=

Comment: @RdmTeen, There is no reason in general why you could not use a `while` loop to implement the behavior you describe, so if your attempt to do so failed then that's do do with the details of your attempt.  If you want to know about that then it's the broken, looping code you need to present (by editing it into your question).  Otherwise, the answer is simply "use a `for` or `while` loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `while(i < 100)` not `while(i > 100)`

This works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    double yes = 0.01;

    while(i < 100) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.println("Do you want to add 1? if yes type in '0.01' ");

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double add = keyboardInput.nextDouble();

        if (yes == add) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("i now is: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```